# Direct json to StructureMap serialized byte[]

Tags: c#, msgpack, utf8json

I have the following JSON (received as byte[] from a web socket):

```
{
    "ev": "T",              // Event Type
    "sym": "MSFT",          // Symbol Ticker
    "x": 4,                 // Exchange ID
    "i": "12345",           // Trade ID
    "z": 3,                 // Tape ( 1=A 2=B 3=C)
    "p": 114.125,           // Price
    "s": 100,               // Trade Size
    "c": [0, 1],           // Trade Conditions
    "t": 1536036818784      // Trade Timestamp ( Unix MS )
}
```

And a structure:

```
struct Trade
{
    [JsonPropertyName("sym")]
    public string  Symbol { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("p")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Currently I am going from JSON to structure (using the amazing `Utf8Json` lib), then from structure to `bytes[]`.

I wish to go straight from JSON to `MessagePack` serialized byte object - as the middle step seems a little redundant.

How can one achieve this keeping the property mappings above?

Ideally, since i receive the JSON as a byte[], I would like to directly use the bytes (instead of encoding to a string - or if this has to be done at least encoding that doesn't add a lot of overhead).

I am OK to use attributes (for the JSON mapping) if this will make things simpler!

I am currently looking at `MessagePackWriter` to a raw buffer (working out memory management if I will need to use `MemoryManager` or just make my own `byte[]` arrays etc).

The idea will be to write the stream directly as i decode, and eliminate the `Trade` structure entirely:

```
private void GetTrade(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, IBufferWriter<byte> bufferWriter)
{
    var trade = new Trade
    {
        TradeConditions = new int[] { }
    };

    // working how to use writer out :)
    var writer = new MessagePackWriter(bufferWriter);

    while (Expect(ref reader, JsonTokenType.PropertyName, JsonTokenType.EndObject))
    {
        var property = reader.GetString();

        switch (property)
        {
            default:
                this.logger.LogError($"decoding {trade.GetType().Name} found unexpected property {property}, skipping");
                reader.Skip();
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.Symbol:
                trade.Symbol = ExpectString(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.Symbol);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.ExchangeId:
                trade.ExchangeId = ExpectInt(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.ExchangeId);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.TradeId:
                trade.TradeId = ExpectString(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.TradeId);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.Tape:
                trade.Tape = ExpectInt(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.Tape);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.Price:
                trade.Price = ExpectDecimal(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.Price);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.TradeSize:
                trade.TradeSize = ExpectDecimal(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.TradeSize);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.TradeConditions:
                trade.TradeConditions = ExpectIntArray(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.TradeConditions);
                break;
            case StreamFieldNames.Timestamp:
                trade.Timestamp = ExpectUnixTimeMilliseconds(ref reader, StreamFieldNames.Timestamp);
                break;
        }
    }
    return trade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are getting byte [] and want to get Trade structure without converting byte[] to string? In this case you can use [Marshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-4.8) library to cast unmanaged object to managed one:

```
    public T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
    {
        T result;
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        try
        {
            result = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
        }
        finally
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

You will need to include `System.Runtime.InteropServices` for this to work. And in this case byte[] will have to contain all fields in structure as declared, so you will not need to have any attributes. You can have more explanation and examples on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25896/Reading-Unmanaged-Data-Into-Structures) website how does this work. While this problem would easily be solved in C or C++, here in C# we don't have pointers, which eases life for us, but also removes some functionality.

Comment: Thanks for taking hte time to reply. No i am looking to go straight from JSON to `StructureMap` schema, I am currently looking at `MessagePackWriter` and `IBufferWriter<byte>`

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Write command?

https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp#messagepackwriter